# Simplify expression to find criterion for existence of equilibrium points

Tags: algebra-precalculus, dynamical-systems

After some algebra, I got to the following criterion for the existence of equilibrium points in an oscillating pendulum:
\begin{equation}
\sin{(2(x_1-\phi))} = 4\delta^2 \, \sin{(x_1)}
\end{equation}
where $\phi$ ranges from 0 to $\pi/2$. In particular, the condition for $\phi=0$ and for $\phi=\pi/2$, the criterion is clear:

1. For $\phi=0$, we have
   \begin{equation}
   \sin{(x_1)}\cos{(x_1)} = 2\delta^2 \, \sin{(x_1)}
   \end{equation}
   and we get $x_1=0+ k\pi$ (with $k\in \mathbb{Z}$) as trivial solutions and $\cos{(x_1)} = 2\delta^2$, for which we need $\delta^2<\frac{1}{2}$.
2. For $\phi=\pi/2$, we have
   \begin{equation}
   -\sin{(x_1)}\cos{(x_1)} = 2\delta^2 \, \sin{(x_1)}
   \end{equation}
   again, we get $x_1=0+ k\pi$ (with $k\in \mathbb{Z}$) as trivial solutions and $\cos{(x_1)} = -2\delta^2$, for which we need $\delta^2<\frac{1}{2}$.

I'm looking for a way to simplify my expression and find the criterion for $\phi$ and $\delta$ by which $x_1$ exists, and then an expression of the form $x_{1,eq} = f(\phi, \delta)$. Send help, please :)

Comment: Are you talking about the simple pendulum $\ddot x=-c^2\sin x$ or some more elaborate physical construct? As constant solutions satisfy $\dot x=0\implies \ddot x=0$, these equilibria satisfy $\sin x=0$.

Comment: It's not exactly the simple pendulum, but a pendulum whose pivot undergoes (sinusoidal) oscillations in a diagonal direction. In particular, the oscillations follow a diagonal direction, tilted an angle $\phi$ with respect to the horizontal.

Comment: Yes, that would follow under "more elaborate". Is the pivot oscillation externally forced or is there some spring or similar holding it in place?

Comment: It is externally forced by a rotor, so the movement is purely sinusoidal in a certain diagonal direction.